# Startindex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startindex

Tags: c#, null, checkedlistbox

Im in learning stage when it comes to C#.

I have a checkedlistbox. So if an item is checked i want it to make a query to database. If nothing is checked it should only query select * from Table.

This is what i have manage to do so far, but i'm failing hard. Any suggestion how i could make it work correctly?

```
private void chkbx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            string query = string.Empty;
            string req = "Select * FROM SME";
            string sql = string.Empty;
            foreach (string s in chkbx.CheckedItems)
                query += s + "','";
            query = query.Remove(query.Length -3);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            {
                query = string.Format(" WHERE Agent IN ('{0}')", query);
            }


            {
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("datasource=server.ip.com;port=12345;database=DB;username=user;password=pass"))
                {

                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(req + query))
                    {
                        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                sda.Fill(dt);
                                dataGrid.DataSource = dt;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: check if query variable is null or empty before calling .Remove ` if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(query)) query = query.Remove(query.Length -3);`

Comment: if looks like your `chkbx.CheckedItems` will have issues if nothing is checked.  Your next line of code is trying to remove stuff from an empty string.  This will throw an error if there are no items...  `query = query.Remove(query.Length -3)`  because length will be 0 so you will be removing the -3 item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a concatenating string your could use

```
string query = "";
List<string> items = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in chkbx.CheckedItems)
    items.Add(s);
if (items.Count > 0)
{
    query = $" WHERE Agent IN ('{string.Join("','", items)}')";
}
```

In this way you add the checked item texts in a list and then use string.Join to build the internal part of the IN clause. The clause is completed adding a single quote before and and after the result of the join

Comment: you missed some quotes when your building your where clause.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any missing quote. Can you pinpoint it? Perhaps the syntax highlightning is misleading here?

Comment: actually you have too many.   I though you were embeding a double but you actually dont need them.   `query = " WHERE Agent IN ({'" + string.Join("','", items) + "'})";`

Comment: that will produce something like  _WHERE Agent IN ({'a','b','c'})_

Comment: check again.  its not even authenticating on this site.

Comment: you have an extra double quote before and after the brackets

Comment: you removed too many now.  LOL.  check my code in my previous post

Comment: @Kevbo I have tested it in LinqPad and it is correct. It produces the correct IN clause, Your example above produces, as explained, an incorrect IN clause with the presence of invalid { } .

Comment: Linqpad must not know how to concatenate properly.  it wont compile in C# for me the way you have it. It needs a closing quote before the join and then an open quote again after it to append the ending bracket.   and you switched the single quote and brackets so now they are backwards.

Comment: OK, just tested also in VS2017 and again it works. My code produces a string like this _WHERE Agent IN ('a','b','c')_ Can you explain what version of VS are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168953/discussion-between-kevbo-and-steve).